# Sdkmanager version

Tags: javascript, java, react-native

When I run `sdkmanager --version` it shows this:

[image: error in sdkmanager]

Btw, currently I want to setup for my react native. And also when I run `react native doctor` it show that my android sdk version is N/A:

[image: output of react native doctor]

Please help whether I should check on my environment variables and so on.

I want to identify the version for my sdkmanager